# Why doesn't my Administrator account have access privileges?

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-accounts

We are running windows server 2003.I log in as Administrator but I don't have any access rights. I tried to create a new Administrator account but when logging into that one I still face the same issue.

Is there a problem with the Group Administrators? If so is there a way to restore it's default settings?

Note: This problem started after I uninstalled the Active directory role from the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Fahad .. suggest you specify the user (domain admin, local admin, another user in domain admin group, etc), what was removed (domain membership, no longer a DC, a specific role), and kind of access is failing.

Comment: If you have no access rights how did you create a local user with admin rights?

Answer (score 1):

If you uninstalled AD Role then the server was moved out of the AD domain and as such all domain accounts can no longer be used to log on to the server. You need a password of the inital administrator account - when you installed the server. The password was reset to that account.

Comment: Side note-if you don't know the password, you might be able to google "chntpw" and use a boot disk like RIP (rescue is possible) to nullify the password. But you need to know a little about Linux to use it or find someone who is more comfortable with using it. It's clumsy but effective.

Comment: I tried your suggestion Bart but sill very much the same.

Comment: The utility said it worked when resetting the password? And you're logging in as the local administrator user?

Comment: I didn't use the utility because I am logged in with the same initial administrator password